# POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded fails

Tags: ruby, typhoeus

I need to send a POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded parameters to a URL. I'm using `Typhoeus` gem for this purpose.

```
@fetch = Typhoeus::Request.post("http://www.diyanet.gov.tr/turkish/namazvakti/vakithes_namazsonuc.asp", :params => {"ulk"=>"TURKIYE", "sehirler"=>"ADANA", "R1"=>"AYLIK"}, :headers=>{"Content-type"=>"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

But I don't get what I expected...

This is Postman (chrome extension) screenshot below. As you can see, I'm setting everything the same and it runs properly at Postman.

[image]

Do you have any idea what's going wrong?

Different solutions/gems are welcomed too...

Comment: Maybe "Content-type" should be "Content-Type"?

Comment: I've tried both of them... :\ No way.

Comment: Any reason why you are using `Typhoeus::Request.post` instead of `Typhoeus.post`? Are you getting any errors either way?

Comment: Nope but there's no problem with syntax though. Doesn't work either way.. :(

Comment: Do you have another alternative for this purpose?

Comment: I pasted your code into pry and it works fine _i.e._ 200 OK with same body. What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: params were not send properly. I've opened an issue and got the answer. Hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus/issues/315) about this.

All I had to was changing `params` with `body`. I think It's about structure of `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters...

Oh my pity 3 hours.